# Update failing for Google Chrome

Tags: apt, google-chrome

Software update is failing at Chrome:

```
Reading package lists... Done
W: GPG error: http://dl.google.com stable Release: The following signatures were invalid: BADSIG A040830F7FAC5991 Google, Inc. Linux Package Signing Key <linux-packages-keymaster@google.com>
```

I've tried deleting and re-installing the Google key:

```
sudo apt-key del A040830F7FAC5991
wget https://dl-ssl.google.com/linux/linux_signing_key.pub
apt-key add linux_signing_key.pub
```

Anyone else having issues?

Comment: Same issue here.

Comment: Same issue. (Trying to update pepperflashplugin-nonfree, which downloads chrome from the google repo.)

Comment: It seems now to have done.

Comment: I added the key based on  http://askubuntu.com/questions/599112/google-chrome-ppa-upgrade-invalid-signature but I'm seeking almost the exact same error.

Answer (score 2):

Open a terminal and enter the following:

```
wget -q -O - https://dl-ssl.google.com/linux/linux_signing_key.pub | sudo apt-key add -
```

That will import Google's updated GPG Key. You should be able to update the system without any errors.

Worked for me on Ubuntu 14.04.2

Source: [Google Linux Repositories](http://www.google.com/linuxrepositories/)

Comment: No need to post [the same answer](/a/599149) to multiple questions, that are likely duplicates.

Answer (score 0):

Delete the previously installed key with:

```
sudo apt-key del 7FAC5991
```

Then download and re-add key.

Answer (score -1):

I know this post is a year old and it is already solved, but I run in the same issue in March 2016 and maybe my answer can help someone.

It seems that google has suspended 32 bit support for chrome, so you have to write in sources.list the architecture for chrome.

I did what is explained here:
http://www.omgubuntu.co.uk/2016/03/fix-failed-to-fetch-google-chrome-apt-error-ubuntu

```
sudo gedit /etc/apt/sources.list.d/google-chrome.list
```

And added "[arch=amd64]" just after "deb".