# Google Chrome PPA upgrade invalid signature

Tags: upgrade, software-installation, google-chrome, ppa, signature

When running:

```
sudo apt-get update && sudo apt-get dist-upgrade
```

I got this output:

```
Ign http://security.ubuntu.com utopic-security InRelease
Ign http://gb.archive.ubuntu.com utopic InRelease                              
Ign http://extras.ubuntu.com utopic InRelease                                  
Get:1 http://security.ubuntu.com utopic-security Release.gpg [933 B]           
Ign http://dl.google.com stable InRelease                                      
Ign http://gb.archive.ubuntu.com utopic-updates InRelease            
Get:2 http://extras.ubuntu.com utopic Release.gpg [72 B]                       
Get:3 http://security.ubuntu.com utopic-security Release [62.0 kB]             
Ign http://gb.archive.ubuntu.com utopic-backports InRelease                    
Get:4 http://dl.google.com stable Release.gpg [198 B]                          
Hit http://extras.ubuntu.com utopic Release                                    
Hit http://gb.archive.ubuntu.com utopic Release.gpg                            
Get:5 http://dl.google.com stable Release [1,347 B]                            
Err http://dl.google.com stable Release                                        

Get:6 http://gb.archive.ubuntu.com utopic-updates Release.gpg [933 B]          
Hit http://extras.ubuntu.com utopic/main Sources                         
Hit http://gb.archive.ubuntu.com utopic-backports Release.gpg
Get:7 http://security.ubuntu.com utopic-security/main Sources [44.6 kB]
Hit http://gb.archive.ubuntu.com utopic Release                                
Hit http://extras.ubuntu.com utopic/main amd64 Packages                        
Get:8 http://gb.archive.ubuntu.com utopic-updates Release [62.0 kB]            
Hit http://extras.ubuntu.com utopic/main i386 Packages                         
Get:9 http://security.ubuntu.com utopic-security/restricted Sources [2,107 B]  
Get:10 http://security.ubuntu.com utopic-security/universe Sources [8,053 B]   
Get:11 http://security.ubuntu.com utopic-security/multiverse Sources [1,951 B] 
Hit http://gb.archive.ubuntu.com utopic-backports Release                      
Get:12 http://security.ubuntu.com utopic-security/main amd64 Packages [129 kB] 
Hit http://gb.archive.ubuntu.com utopic/main Sources                           
Hit http://gb.archive.ubuntu.com utopic/restricted Sources                     
Hit http://gb.archive.ubuntu.com utopic/universe Sources                       
Hit http://gb.archive.ubuntu.com utopic/multiverse Sources              
Get:13 http://security.ubuntu.com utopic-security/restricted amd64 Packages [8,496 B]
Hit http://gb.archive.ubuntu.com utopic/main amd64 Packages                    
Get:14 http://security.ubuntu.com utopic-security/universe amd64 Packages [54.4 kB]
Hit http://gb.archive.ubuntu.com utopic/restricted amd64 Packages              
Ign http://extras.ubuntu.com utopic/main Translation-en_GB                     
Hit http://gb.archive.ubuntu.com utopic/universe amd64 Packages                
Ign http://extras.ubuntu.com utopic/main Translation-en                        
Get:15 http://security.ubuntu.com utopic-security/multiverse amd64 Packages [4,139 B]
Hit http://gb.archive.ubuntu.com utopic/multiverse amd64 Packages              
Hit http://gb.archive.ubuntu.com utopic/main i386 Packages                     
Get:16 http://security.ubuntu.com utopic-security/main i386 Packages [128 kB]
Hit http://gb.archive.ubuntu.com utopic/restricted i386 Packages       
Hit http://gb.archive.ubuntu.com utopic/universe i386 Packages                 
Get:17 http://security.ubuntu.com utopic-security/restricted i386 Packages [8,438 B]
Hit http://gb.archive.ubuntu.com utopic/multiverse i386 Packages               
Get:18 http://security.ubuntu.com utopic-security/universe i386 Packages [54.4 kB]
Hit http://gb.archive.ubuntu.com utopic/main Translation-en_GB                 
Hit http://gb.archive.ubuntu.com utopic/main Translation-en                    
Get:19 http://security.ubuntu.com utopic-security/multiverse i386 Packages [4,325 B]
Hit http://gb.archive.ubuntu.com utopic/multiverse Translation-en_GB           
Hit http://security.ubuntu.com utopic-security/main Translation-en
Hit http://gb.archive.ubuntu.com utopic/multiverse Translation-en
Hit http://security.ubuntu.com utopic-security/multiverse Translation-en
Hit http://gb.archive.ubuntu.com utopic/restricted Translation-en_GB
Hit http://security.ubuntu.com utopic-security/restricted Translation-en
Hit http://gb.archive.ubuntu.com utopic/restricted Translation-en
Hit http://gb.archive.ubuntu.com utopic/universe Translation-en_GB
Hit http://gb.archive.ubuntu.com utopic/universe Translation-en
Get:20 http://gb.archive.ubuntu.com utopic-updates/main Sources [81.0 kB]
Hit http://security.ubuntu.com utopic-security/universe Translation-en 
Get:21 http://gb.archive.ubuntu.com utopic-updates/restricted Sources [2,107 B]
Get:22 http://gb.archive.ubuntu.com utopic-updates/universe Sources [19.9 kB]
Get:23 http://gb.archive.ubuntu.com utopic-updates/multiverse Sources [1,951 B]
Get:24 http://gb.archive.ubuntu.com utopic-updates/main amd64 Packages [208 kB]
Get:25 http://gb.archive.ubuntu.com utopic-updates/restricted amd64 Packages [8,496 B]
Get:26 http://gb.archive.ubuntu.com utopic-updates/universe amd64 Packages [81.3 kB]
Get:27 http://gb.archive.ubuntu.com utopic-updates/multiverse amd64 Packages [4,139 B]
Get:28 http://gb.archive.ubuntu.com utopic-updates/main i386 Packages [207 kB] 
Get:29 http://gb.archive.ubuntu.com utopic-updates/restricted i386 Packages [8,438 B]
Get:30 http://gb.archive.ubuntu.com utopic-updates/universe i386 Packages [81.3 kB]
Get:31 http://gb.archive.ubuntu.com utopic-updates/multiverse i386 Packages [4,325 B]
Hit http://gb.archive.ubuntu.com utopic-updates/main Translation-en               
Hit http://gb.archive.ubuntu.com utopic-updates/multiverse Translation-en
Hit http://gb.archive.ubuntu.com utopic-updates/restricted Translation-en
Hit http://gb.archive.ubuntu.com utopic-updates/universe Translation-en
Hit http://gb.archive.ubuntu.com utopic-backports/main Sources
Hit http://gb.archive.ubuntu.com utopic-backports/restricted Sources
Hit http://gb.archive.ubuntu.com utopic-backports/multiverse Sources
Hit http://gb.archive.ubuntu.com utopic-backports/universe Sources
Hit http://gb.archive.ubuntu.com utopic-backports/main amd64 Packages
Hit http://gb.archive.ubuntu.com utopic-backports/restricted amd64 Packages
Hit http://gb.archive.ubuntu.com utopic-backports/multiverse amd64 Packages
Hit http://gb.archive.ubuntu.com utopic-backports/universe amd64 Packages
Hit http://gb.archive.ubuntu.com utopic-backports/main i386 Packages
Hit http://gb.archive.ubuntu.com utopic-backports/restricted i386 Packages
Hit http://gb.archive.ubuntu.com utopic-backports/multiverse i386 Packages
Hit http://gb.archive.ubuntu.com utopic-backports/universe i386 Packages
Hit http://gb.archive.ubuntu.com utopic-backports/main Translation-en
Hit http://gb.archive.ubuntu.com utopic-backports/multiverse Translation-en
Hit http://gb.archive.ubuntu.com utopic-backports/restricted Translation-en
Hit http://gb.archive.ubuntu.com utopic-backports/universe Translation-en
Fetched 1,283 kB in 6s (207 kB/s)                                                                                                              
Reading package lists... Done
W: An error occurred during the signature verification. The repository is not updated and the previous index files will be used. GPG error: http://dl.google.com stable Release: The following signatures were invalid: BADSIG A040830F7FAC5991 Google, Inc. Linux Package Signing Key <linux-packages-keymaster@google.com>

W: Failed to fetch http://dl.google.com/linux/chrome/deb/dists/stable/Release  

W: Some index files failed to download. They have been ignored, or old ones used instead.
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
Calculating upgrade... Done
0 to upgrade, 0 to newly install, 0 to remove and 0 not to upgrade.
```

Is this bit:

```
W: An error occurred during the signature verification. The repository is not updated and the previous index files will be used. GPG error: http://dl.google.com stable Release: The following signatures were invalid: BADSIG A040830F7FAC5991 Google, Inc. Linux Package Signing Key <linux-packages-keymaster@google.com>

W: Failed to fetch http://dl.google.com/linux/chrome/deb/dists/stable/Release  

W: Some index files failed to download. They have been ignored, or old ones used instead.
```

Anything to worry about? I ran the commands again and now it says:

```
Ign http://extras.ubuntu.com utopic InRelease
Ign http://dl.google.com stable InRelease                                                        
Ign http://gb.archive.ubuntu.com utopic InRelease                                                 
Hit http://extras.ubuntu.com utopic Release.gpg                                                   
Ign http://gb.archive.ubuntu.com utopic-updates InRelease                                         
Get:1 http://dl.google.com stable Release.gpg [198 B]                                                                   
Hit http://extras.ubuntu.com utopic Release                                                                                        
Ign http://gb.archive.ubuntu.com utopic-backports InRelease                                       
Hit http://gb.archive.ubuntu.com utopic Release.gpg                                         
Get:2 http://dl.google.com stable Release [1,347 B]                                         
Get:3 http://gb.archive.ubuntu.com utopic-updates Release.gpg [933 B]  
Hit http://gb.archive.ubuntu.com utopic-backports Release.gpg          
Ign http://security.ubuntu.com utopic-security InRelease               
Hit http://gb.archive.ubuntu.com utopic Release                        
Get:4 http://gb.archive.ubuntu.com utopic-updates Release [62.0 kB]                                              
Hit http://extras.ubuntu.com utopic/main Sources                                                                         
Get:5 http://security.ubuntu.com utopic-security Release.gpg [933 B]                                                     
Get:6 http://dl.google.com stable/main amd64 Packages [1,193 B]                                      
Hit http://extras.ubuntu.com utopic/main amd64 Packages                                                                                     
Hit http://gb.archive.ubuntu.com utopic-backports Release                                   
Hit http://extras.ubuntu.com utopic/main i386 Packages                                                             
Get:7 http://dl.google.com stable/main i386 Packages [1,176 B]                              
Get:8 http://security.ubuntu.com utopic-security Release [62.0 kB]                                         
Ign http://extras.ubuntu.com utopic/main Translation-en_GB                                           
Ign http://extras.ubuntu.com utopic/main Translation-en                        
Ign http://dl.google.com stable/main Translation-en_GB                         
Ign http://dl.google.com stable/main Translation-en                      
Get:9 http://security.ubuntu.com utopic-security/main Sources [44.6 kB]
Get:10 http://security.ubuntu.com utopic-security/restricted Sources [2,107 B]
Get:11 http://gb.archive.ubuntu.com utopic-updates/main Sources [81.0 kB]
Get:12 http://security.ubuntu.com utopic-security/universe Sources [8,053 B]
Get:13 http://gb.archive.ubuntu.com utopic-updates/restricted Sources [2,107 B]  
Get:14 http://security.ubuntu.com utopic-security/multiverse Sources [1,951 B]    
Get:15 http://gb.archive.ubuntu.com utopic-updates/universe Sources [19.9 kB]     
Get:16 http://gb.archive.ubuntu.com utopic-updates/multiverse Sources [1,951 B]
Get:17 http://gb.archive.ubuntu.com utopic-updates/main amd64 Packages [208 kB]
Get:18 http://security.ubuntu.com utopic-security/main amd64 Packages [129 kB]
Get:19 http://gb.archive.ubuntu.com utopic-updates/restricted amd64 Packages [8,496 B]
Get:20 http://security.ubuntu.com utopic-security/restricted amd64 Packages [8,496 B]
Get:21 http://gb.archive.ubuntu.com utopic-updates/universe amd64 Packages [81.3 kB]
Get:22 http://security.ubuntu.com utopic-security/universe amd64 Packages [54.4 kB]
Get:23 http://gb.archive.ubuntu.com utopic-updates/multiverse amd64 Packages [4,139 B]         
Get:24 http://gb.archive.ubuntu.com utopic-updates/main i386 Packages [207 kB]      
Get:25 http://security.ubuntu.com utopic-security/multiverse amd64 Packages [4,139 B]
Get:26 http://security.ubuntu.com utopic-security/main i386 Packages [128 kB]     
Get:27 http://gb.archive.ubuntu.com utopic-updates/restricted i386 Packages [8,438 B]
Get:28 http://gb.archive.ubuntu.com utopic-updates/universe i386 Packages [81.3 kB]           
Get:29 http://gb.archive.ubuntu.com utopic-updates/multiverse i386 Packages [4,325 B]        
Get:30 http://security.ubuntu.com utopic-security/restricted i386 Packages [8,438 B]
Get:31 http://gb.archive.ubuntu.com utopic-backports/main Sources [765 B]          
Hit http://gb.archive.ubuntu.com utopic-backports/restricted Sources    
Hit http://gb.archive.ubuntu.com utopic-backports/multiverse Sources    
Get:32 http://security.ubuntu.com utopic-security/universe i386 Packages [54.4 kB]
Get:33 http://gb.archive.ubuntu.com utopic-backports/universe Sources [9,218 B]
Get:34 http://gb.archive.ubuntu.com utopic-backports/main amd64 Packages [570 B]  
Hit http://gb.archive.ubuntu.com utopic-backports/restricted amd64 Packages      
Hit http://gb.archive.ubuntu.com utopic-backports/multiverse amd64 Packages
Get:35 http://security.ubuntu.com utopic-security/multiverse i386 Packages [4,325 B]
Get:36 http://gb.archive.ubuntu.com utopic-backports/universe amd64 Packages [10.6 kB]
Get:37 http://gb.archive.ubuntu.com utopic-backports/main i386 Packages [574 B]
Hit http://gb.archive.ubuntu.com utopic-backports/restricted i386 Packages
Hit http://gb.archive.ubuntu.com utopic-backports/multiverse i386 Packages
Get:38 http://gb.archive.ubuntu.com utopic-backports/universe i386 Packages [10.6 kB]
Hit http://gb.archive.ubuntu.com utopic-backports/multiverse Translation-en
Hit http://gb.archive.ubuntu.com utopic-backports/restricted Translation-en
Hit http://gb.archive.ubuntu.com utopic/main Sources
Hit http://gb.archive.ubuntu.com utopic/restricted Sources    
Hit http://gb.archive.ubuntu.com utopic/universe Sources      
Hit http://gb.archive.ubuntu.com utopic/multiverse Sources
Hit http://gb.archive.ubuntu.com utopic/main amd64 Packages
Hit http://gb.archive.ubuntu.com utopic/restricted amd64 Packages
Hit http://gb.archive.ubuntu.com utopic/universe amd64 Packages
Hit http://gb.archive.ubuntu.com utopic/multiverse amd64 Packages
Hit http://gb.archive.ubuntu.com utopic/main i386 Packages
Hit http://gb.archive.ubuntu.com utopic/restricted i386 Packages   
Hit http://gb.archive.ubuntu.com utopic/universe i386 Packages     
Hit http://security.ubuntu.com utopic-security/main Translation-en 
Hit http://gb.archive.ubuntu.com utopic/multiverse i386 Packages   
Hit http://gb.archive.ubuntu.com utopic/main Translation-en_GB     
Hit http://gb.archive.ubuntu.com utopic/main Translation-en        
Hit http://gb.archive.ubuntu.com utopic/multiverse Translation-en_GB
Hit http://security.ubuntu.com utopic-security/multiverse Translation-en
Hit http://gb.archive.ubuntu.com utopic/multiverse Translation-en
Hit http://gb.archive.ubuntu.com utopic/restricted Translation-en_GB
Hit http://gb.archive.ubuntu.com utopic/restricted Translation-en
Hit http://gb.archive.ubuntu.com utopic/universe Translation-en_GB
Hit http://security.ubuntu.com utopic-security/restricted Translation-en
Hit http://gb.archive.ubuntu.com utopic/universe Translation-en
Hit http://gb.archive.ubuntu.com utopic-updates/main Translation-en
Hit http://gb.archive.ubuntu.com utopic-updates/multiverse Translation-en
Hit http://gb.archive.ubuntu.com utopic-updates/restricted Translation-en
Hit http://security.ubuntu.com utopic-security/universe Translation-en
Hit http://gb.archive.ubuntu.com utopic-updates/universe Translation-en
Hit http://gb.archive.ubuntu.com utopic-backports/main Translation-en
Hit http://gb.archive.ubuntu.com utopic-backports/universe Translation-en
Fetched 1,316 kB in 11s (115 kB/s)                                                                                                             
Reading package lists... Done
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
Calculating upgrade... Done
The following packages will be upgraded:
  google-chrome-stable
1 to upgrade, 0 to newly install, 0 to remove and 0 not to upgrade.
Need to get 48.5 MB of archives.
After this operation, 4,096 B of additional disk space will be used.
Do you want to continue? [Y/n]
```

So what does this mean and should I trust this upgrade? This upgrade is from a PPA that Google Chrome added when I installed it from the official Google page for it.

Here is more information about that PPA:

[image: Google Chrome PPA]

---

**OS Information:**

```
Description:    Ubuntu 14.10
Release:    14.10
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of http://askubuntu.com/questions/598979/update-failing-for-google-chrome (but can't flag because that question has no answer.)

Answer (score 70, accepted):

Open a terminal and enter the following:

```
wget -q -O - https://dl-ssl.google.com/linux/linux_signing_key.pub | sudo apt-key add -
```

That will import Google's updated GPG Key.

You should be able to update the system without any errors.

Source: [Google Linux Repositories](http://www.google.com/linuxrepositories/)

Comment: The problem is that is failing too, randomly. My build is running on TravisCI and some of them are failing for the same reason. I correctly install the key exactly like what you've shown above. It just started recently. =(

Comment: I had that key already and it was working up until a couple of days ago.  I deleted the key that I had and used the above command but it didn't resolve the problem. I still had the invalid signature error.  The answer from mikhail resolved the problem for me. No more GPG errors and a new update for Google Chrome appeared.

Comment: This fixed error `NO_PUBKEY 6494C6D6997C215E`

Answer (score 30):

This site has the only solution that worked for me on 64-bit Ubuntu 14.04 LTS:

http://www.omgubuntu.co.uk/2016/03/fix-failed-to-fetch-google-chrome-apt-error-ubuntu

(Here's a summary. Please see the site for more detail)

1. Edit google-chrome.list (assuming you’re on the Stable Channel, if not, see the featured comment on the site):

   ```
   sudo gedit /etc/apt/sources.list.d/google-chrome.list
   ```
2. In the text file that opens edit the file so that the line reads:

   ```
   deb [arch=amd64] http://dl.google.com/linux/chrome/deb/ stable main
   ```
3. Try update again

   ```
   sudo apt-get update
   ```

Comment: What does the` amd64` tag do, exactly? Is this invalid for some distributions?

Comment: It points you to the 64 bit releases of Chrome. More details in the linked article.

Comment: This helped me, although my error was different from the OP. It was `W: Failed to fetch http://dl.google.com/linux/chrome/deb/dists/stable/Release: Unable to find expected entry 'main/binary-i386/Packages' in Release file (Wrong sources.list entry or malformed file)`

Comment: @frant.hartm same problem, and yes this fix worked for me too.

Answer (score 26):

This will work better than these solutions:

```
apt-key list google
```

You will see this on this list, take not [E] means expired and look at the last `7FAC 5991`

```
pub   dsa1024 2007-03-08 [SC]
      4CCA 1EAF 950C EE4A B839  76DC A040 830F 7FAC 5991
uid           [ unknown] Google, Inc. Linux Package Signing Key <linux-packages-keymaster@google.com>
sub   elg2048 2007-03-08 [E]

pub   rsa4096 2016-04-12 [SC]
      EB4C 1BFD 4F04 2F6D DDCC  EC91 7721 F63B D38B 4796
uid           [ unknown] Google Inc. (Linux Packages Signing Authority) <linux-packages-keymaster@google.com>
sub   rsa4096 2016-04-12 [S] [expires: 2019-04-12]
```

You will do now:

```
sudo apt-key del 7FAC5991
```

Then you will do these commands:

```
sudo apt-get clean
cd /var/lib/apt
sudo mv lists lists.old
sudo mkdir -p lists/partial
sudo apt-get clean
sudo apt-get update
```

And after that's done you will do this to [install keyring](https://www.google.com/linuxrepositories/) from another keyserver:

```
wget -q -O - https://dl.google.com/linux/linux_signing_key.pub | sudo apt-key add -
```

And then you do:

```
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get dist-upgrade
```

Now you are all set. :)

Comment: Thank you this worked for me no more complaints about invalid GPG key and a new version of Google Chrome in updates.

Comment: I made the same on my Kubuntu 15.04. The gpg --recv-keys command only worked for me after add "0x" before the BADSIG number. So, the command was  

gpg --keyserver hkp://subkeys.pgp.net --recv-keys 0xA040830F7FAC5991

Comment: I keep getting timeout errors with `hkp://subkeys.pgp.net` - I used `hkp://gpg.mit.edu` and that works.

Comment: Worked for me on 15.10 as is, with no modifications to keyid or url.

Comment: After deleting the keys  the 'apt-get clean; apt-get update' step, I get the error 'W: GPG error: http://dl.google.com stable Release: The following signatures couldn't be verified because the public key is not available: NO_PUBKEY A040830F7FAC5991 NO_PUBKEY 1397BC53640DB551;'  What else can I try?

Comment: I don't think this question is neccessary at all, deleting expired keys is fun but it's not useful. Anyway, I updated to show how it works. Aslo that simple command provided by google does the same thing a lot easier. this still doesn't work for me.

Comment: The other answers didn't cut it for me - this should be marked as the correct answer

Answer (score 1):

I had to download the key file from Google https://www.google.com/linuxrepositories/ and import it into the software sources authentication.

Upon re-running Sudo Apt Update I was given the option to respond to the question

```
Hit:8 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu bionic-updates InRelease
Hit:9 http://packages.linuxmint.com tara Release
Hit:10 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu bionic-backports InRelease
E: Repository 'http://dl.google.com/linux/chrome/deb stable Release' changed its 'Origin' value from 'Google, Inc.' to 'Google LLC'
N: This must be accepted explicitly before updates for this repository can be applied. See apt-secure(8) manpage for details.
Do you want to accept these changes and continue updating from this repository?
[y/N] y
Get:11 http://dl.google.com/linux/chrome/deb stable/main amd64 Packages [1,130 B] Fetched 2,892 B in 4s (705 B/s)
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree
Reading state information... Done
All packages are up-to-date.
```

Hope this helps somebody